# scanf gets the input of the previously excecuted getchar()

Tags: c, buffer, scanf, getchar

I am using getchar() in order to read characters and put them on a table, as well as scanf in order to get an integer.

The problem with the scanf() is that it doesn't wait for the users' input but reads from the buffer the last character given on the previous line, with getchar().

I tried sscanf, fflush(stdin); etc but I'm getting still the same behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


main()
{
    int i, choice, tmp_day, tmp_month;
    char name[5];

    printf("insert choice(1-3):\n");
    scanf("%d",&choice);


    printf("name: ");
    for (i=0;i<5;i++) name[i]=getchar();

    name[5] = '\0' ;

    printf("day (1-31): ");

    scanf("%d",&tmp_day);

    printf("month (1-12): ");

    scanf("%d",&tmp_month);

    printf("\n%d %d", tmp_day, tmp_month);

}
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: char name[5]; -> char name[6];index 0..5 = size is 6

Answer (score 1):

Detailed discussion about `fflush(stdin)` which not necessarily portable.

```
http://c-faq.com/stdio/gets_flush2.html
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not enough. He suggests fgets and sscanf but there still is a problem with the \n character of the fgets which is not consumed. So I finally, combined that with the custom cleanBuffer (that using the    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)    )

Comment: It seems that the best combination is getline and sscanf. As described here http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/fgets.html, fgets is deprecated

Comment: gets is actually no longer part of the C11 standard.  fgets() is.  So I suspect you meant that gets was obsoleted.   I  like to think it was outlawed.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output

Comment: I meant fgets is obsoleted: "The fgets ("file get string") function is similar to the gets function. This function is deprecated".
This is why I used getline but I think getline also has problems in some compilers used in windows.. must check it..

Answer (score 0):

After each scanf use this statement:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

Comment: did you mean `fflush(stdin);`?

Comment: Not just a typo, undefined behavior too.